# Race condition in Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, request, race-condition

I am learning Node.js and doing a practice for API. I would like to get data from twitch about the top 200 streams of a game. However, due to the limit is 100, so I have to do twice request in the for-loop. The question is the **race condition**. When I request the data from 0-100 and 100-200, I do not know which one of data will come first. So, I flag the status for record which one comes first, but it seems not working correctly. Can anyone guide me what wrong is of my method? How to improve it? Thank you!

```
const request = require('request');
const process = require('process');

const args = process.argv[2];
let offset = 0;
let flag = false;
const clientID = 'agdn5682y521syqhwkdrqmw7ho6v7d';

function getGameInfo(gamename, pagination, clientid, tag) {
  request(
    {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?game=${gamename}&limit=100&offset=${pagination}`,
      headers: {
        'Client-ID': clientid,
        'Accept': 'application / vnd.twitchtv.v5 + json'
      }
    },
    (err, res, body) => {
      if (!tag) {
        tag = true;
        if (err) {
          return console.log('Error', err)
        };
        const data = JSON.parse(body);

        const result = data.streams;

        if (data.status === 404) {
          console.log('fail to get data!');
        };
        for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
          console.log(result[j].channel._id, result[j].channel.display_name);
        };
        tag = false;
      }
    }
  )
}

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  getGameInfo(args, offset, clientID);
  offset += 100;
}
```

Comment: You can use promise.

Comment: @xMayank, Yes, I noticed that lots people using promise, it is a good suggestion, but I like to practice how avoid race condition in the above code. Thank you!

Comment: There is no race condition. Node js handles IO asynchronously and does not wait for response. Look into axios library, and use async/await. This will improve the code a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small example you can do. Promise waits until it gets `resolve()`

Then you can call next offset.

```
const request = require('request');
const process = require('process');

const args = process.argv[2];
let offset = 0;
let flag = false;
const clientID = 'agdn5682y521syqhwkdrqmw7ho6v7d';



function getGameInfo(args, offset, clientID){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/?game=${args}&limit=100&offset=${offset}`,
      headers: {
        'Client-ID': clientID,
        'Accept': 'application / vnd.twitchtv.v5 + json'
      }
    }
        request(options, function (err, response, body) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            try {
                resolve(JSON.parse(body));
            } catch(e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
}

getGameInfo("pubg", offset, clientID).then(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```